# Pass brace-enclosed initializer list of fixed length to function

Tags: c++, arrays, aggregate-initialization

I want to make it possible to pass brace-enclosed initializer list to my constructor of my class which represents a matrix of fixed dimension. This is the code what I have:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
using array2d = std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>;

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix {
    private:
        array2d<T, N, M> value;
    public:
        Matrix(const array2d<T, N, M>& value) : value(value) {}
};

int main() {
    Matrix<double, 2, 3> mat1 ({
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6}
    });
}
```

My assumption was that `array2d` is automatically created from initializer list that I'm passing as argument to constructor, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as the compiler throws the following error:

```
1704186652/source.cpp:16:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Matrix<double, 2, 3>'
        Matrix<double, 2, 3> mat1 ({
                             ^     ~
1704186652/source.cpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const Matrix<double, 2, 3>'
class Matrix {
      ^
1704186652/source.cpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'Matrix<double, 2, 3>'
class Matrix {
      ^
1704186652/source.cpp:12:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const array2d<double, 2UL, 3UL>' (aka 'const std::__1::array<std::__1::array<double, 2>, 3>')
                Matrix(const array2d<T, N, M>& value) : value(value) {}
                ^
```

Comment: But why do you want to implement a custom version of matrix? There are many libraries that can do it for you.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: @TheOldJonny because that is the homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you have your dimensions reversed.

```
Matrix<double, 2, 3>
```

If you expand your template, this becomes

```
std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3>
```

Or a three element array with each element being two values, and not a two element array with three values per element.

Braced initialization lists, with nested constructors and parameters, sometimes can be a challenge to decipher, and quite often you just have to poke and scribble randomly until it compiles. The following compiles with gcc 10.2, and checked with a debugger that everything is where it should be. My best attempt at explaining the braces:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
using array2d = std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>;

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix {
    private:
        array2d<T, N, M> value;
    public:
        Matrix(const array2d<T, N, M>& value) : value(value) {}
};

int main() {
    Matrix<double, 2, 3> mat1({ // Initializing the 1st constructor parameter
            { // std::array<   ,3> using initializer_list constructor

                // Initializing std::array<T, 2>s
                {1, 2},
                {3, 4},
                {5, 6}
            },
        });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess the correct answer would be to keep the structure of the matrix, but rather swap type parameters N and M in array2d to `using array2d = std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>;`

Comment: Well, if this was your original intent, this would be 100%, guaranteed, unequivocally, true.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend to use @SamVarshavchik's solution. But if you want to save a pair of `{}`, you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
using array2d = std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>;

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class Matrix {
    private:
        array2d<T, N, M> value;
    public:
        Matrix(const array2d<T, N, M>& value) : value(value) {
            std::cout << "using array2d" << std::endl;}
        Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::array<double,N>> values)   {
            // Assign values to this->value
            std::cout << "using initializer list" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {

    array2d<double, 2, 3> values;
    Matrix<double, 2, 3> mat0(values);
    Matrix<double, 2, 3> mat1({{1, 2},{3, 4},{5, 6}});
    Matrix<double, 2, 3> mat2({{1, 2},{3, 4},{5, 6},{7,8}}); // > 3 rows but compiles
    //Matrix<double, 2, 4> mat3({{{1, 2},{3, 4},{5, 6}}}); // <- ambiguous. Note the extra "{}"

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
using array2d
using initializer list
```

Assigning the values of the list to your `this->value` is left as a homework.

**Note that you can add more rows to the initializer list than there are rows in your matrix.** When using this solution, you should provide a runtime check. For this reason I prefer @SamVarshavchik's solution, there the compiler tells you what's wrong.